# Poor RMSEA/Fit for Simple Poisson Regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, goodness-of-fit, poisson-regression, rms

I am running a simple Poisson regression. $X$ = time, $Y$ = count data. This is a huge dataset with many years. There is significance between $X$ and $Y$. But model shows poor fit via high RMSEA value.

The variance is also above the mean, which can contribute to that...due to low DF. I just want to know if $X$ is predictive of $Y$. Any solutions? Does my results mean anything? What should I do instead. I've adjusted for assumptions (distribution etc.).

Comment: What do your plots show? What is the overall trend? (independent of the $p$ values and RMSEA). What is "high" RMSEA here? I would edit this info into your question to get a better answer.